# How to add all facebook friends as a tester at a time on facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to know

1. how to add all facebook friends as a tester at a time on facebook app?
2. What is the maximum number of testers I can add at a time?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can´t. And you shouldn´t.
2. There may be a limit, but if you hit it you are most likely doing something you are not supposed to do.

Btw, there is no use case for adding everyone as Tester, unless you want to do something that is not allowed and avoid going through [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review). That does not mean Facebook can´t ban your App or your account, so don´t do it, if that´s the case.

Comment: There is a limit but it is high